# Java 9 Modularity with a packages

Tags: java, java-9, modularity, java-module

Let's say I have 2 modules:

- module1 has the package `package1`
- module2 has `package2`, `package3` and `package4`

I want `package1` to be visible to only `package2` in module2. not to any other packages (`package3` or `package4`) in module2.

Is this possible using module-info.java?

Comment: BTW modules aside, you can't do it in one module itself. It's either package private or public.

Comment: I am wondering what exactly is your use case without the JPMS in play as well? Not able to understand what you desire here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can only export a package to the whole module:

```
module module1 {
    exports package1 to module2;
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to quote the JLS to support that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7